# Axios.get is showing Network Error when made get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am building a react app and I am trying to make `get request` using `axios`, I am trying to access `imdb` page like :-

> https://www.imdb.com/find?q=Tom%20Hanks

But when I call the `axios` then it is showing

> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
> code: "ERR_NETWORK"
> config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
> message: "Network Error"
> name: "AxiosError"
> request: XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined, onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, …}
> response: XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined, onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, …}
> [[Prototype]]: Error

But When I try to access `localhost` using `axios` then it is working fine
But not working with `imdb`

then I tried accessing `imdb` with `python requests` then it is showing `200` **SUCCESS**.

I have tried many times But it is showing that error everytime.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
           axios.get('https://www.imdb.com/find?q=Tom%20Hanks').then(res => {
             console.log(res)
          }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
    }

    render() {
      return(<div>Good Luck</div>)
   }
}
```

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Comment: You cannot send a request to a third-party website from a browsers. You should read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: @Enve, Thanks for suggesstion. How can I set `CORS` with axios ?

Comment: You can't, unless you own imdb.com. You cannot send a request to IMDB from a users browser, it's a security issue. Please read the article I sent above.

Comment: Can I send with server, I meant by `python-requests` ? As you said, "can't with browser"

Comment: This should help you with CORS and react frontends : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

Comment: @DooMGuy096, Just five minutes, I am trying

Comment: Yes you can, you can make a python page that takes a parameter for example: `localhost/fetchRequest?url=imdb.com\/find?q=Tom%20Hanks` which fetches the content of the `url` and returns it to you. However imdb is likely not going to like that and if it detects a bot scraping its content it will block your IP address.

Comment: @DooMGuy096, It is working but it is not showing full html and it is really difficult and a little bit Odd for extracting element

Comment: @ded — It's a website not an API. Use the API. https://developer.imdb.com/

Comment: Another good movie API : https://developers.themoviedb.org/3